# Conditional for insert into - Java

Tags: java, if-statement, db2, conditional-statements

I need to create a condition to insert or not the data in a table.
There are 11 fields and from 6 to 11 the user may or may not fill it out. If not, It can't save any data in this table. The condition, if the field is white, null or empty, was create, but the insert is being made . Does anyone know how to fix? Thank you!
**ps. When one of the information is not filled in by the user, the insert should not be made**

```
        try {
        PreparedStatement ps_SOFVDISN = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_INSERT_SOFVDISN);

        for (BeanItem beanItem : beanItemLista) {

            ps_SOFVDISN.setString(1, beanItem.getChaveSolicitacao().getCodEstb()); 
            ps_SOFVDISN.setString(2, beanItem.getChaveSolicitacao().getCodPedi()); 
            ps_SOFVDISN.setString(3, beanItem.getChaveSolicitacao().getNumSolcServ()); 
            ps_SOFVDISN.setString(4, beanItem.getItemSs().getNumItemSs()); // NUM_ITEM 
            ps_SOFVDISN.setString(5, " "); 
            ps_SOFVDISN.setString(6, beanItem.getNotaFiscalRef().getSerNfRef()); 
            ps_SOFVDISN.setString(7, beanItem.getNotaFiscalRef().getNumNfRef()); 
            ps_SOFVDISN.setString(8, "");
            ps_SOFVDISN.setString(9, ""); 
            ps_SOFVDISN.setString(10, beanItem.getNotaFiscalRef().getCgcEstbRef());
            ps_SOFVDISN.setString(11, beanItem.getNotaFiscalRef().getQtdUsadaReferencia()); 
        
            if (beanItem.getNotaFiscalRef().getSerNfRef() != null && !beanItem.getNotaFiscalRef().getSerNfRef().trim().equals("") 
                || beanItem.getNotaFiscalRef().getNumNfRef() != null && !beanItem.getNotaFiscalRef().getNumNfRef().trim().equals("")  
                || beanItem.getNotaFiscalRef().getCgcEstbRef() != null && !beanItem.getNotaFiscalRef().getCgcEstbRef().trim().equals("") 
                || beanItem.getNotaFiscalRef().getQtdUsadaReferencia() != null && 
                !beanItem.getNotaFiscalRef().getQtdUsadaReferencia().trim().equals("") && !beanItem.getNotaFiscalRef().getQtdUsadaReferencia().equals(" "))
            {
                        
                if (ps_SOFVDISN.executeUpdate() == 1) {
                    System.out.println("Sucess - Insert ok");
                    retornoResult = true;
                }
            }
```

Comment: So for some reason, the logic in your (rather complicated) if statement is returning true. The trick is o find out which clause it is. you have a mixture of OR and AND, so I would suggest bracketing the AND parts.

Comment: @jr593 I will try use more bracketing. Thanks!

Comment: @jr593 It didn't work :(

Comment: If __all__ the fields are mandatory (cannot be null or empty string) then your `if` statement is incorrect, each condition should be anded not or'ed (as shown in your code in the question).

Comment: @jr593 Fields are not mandatory in the FrontEnd. If all fields are filled in the insert must be done, but if one of the fields is not filled, the insert should not be done.

Answer (score 0):

and what about adding not null constraint in database for columns, which user must define?

Comment: I don't know if I understand, but I think it doesn't work because it must be possible to fill in the field.

Answer (score 0):

Outside of adding null constraints, you can use the ternary operator to check if those fields are null or empty before setting them.

`ps_SOFVDISN.setString(6, !beanItem.getNotaFiscalRef().getSerNfRef().isEmpty() ? beanItem.getNotaFiscalRef().getSerNfRef() : "");`

Comment: Thanks! But If any of the fields are not filled in by the user, the insert cannot be made.

Answer (score 0):

Look into either DB Constraints or Java bean validation frameworks. You want to validate your data before allowing it into your DB.

Generally, I would recommend one of these 3 options in this order to handle your validation:

1. Use the DB Constraints (Easy to do, Guaranteed, Good for many simple use cases)
2. Use a framework (Good for complex use cases)
3. Write validation yourself to kick out before INSERT

There are more pros and cons to each approach, but too much to get into here.

Comment: I can't changing DB Constraints, so I need changin on Java. I created the conditions, but I can't understand why the insertion is done even if the data is not filled in by the user. Thank you!

Comment: I think your problem is you chose Option #3 and wrote the validation incorrectly. You generally have patterened if(A != null && !AisEmpty || B != null && !BisEmpty || ...)... What that means is any ONE of your required fields being valid allows the insert to proceed. You probably want your ||'s to be &&'s so you have ALL fields MUST be non-null *AND* not EMPTY.